# My service can't set WinXP sound mixer props on remote computer when launched from a remote login session

Tags: windows, visual-c++, remote-desktop, audio

The title didn't scare you off. Great!
This is what I'm trying to do:
I have a service that at some point in time plays a very important sound. Because it is so important, I make sure that the mixer is ummuted and that the volume is at a proper level at startup.
This works fine when I start the service logged on locally to the computer where it's executing. 
However, when I start the service from a remote desktop session it fails to get the volume control if I select "Play on this computer" when logging on. 
The obvious solution is "Select 'Play on remote computer' when logging on" but for various usability reasons this is not feasible.

So; the M$ question is: "how can a service launched from remote desktop session set the local mixer main volume if 'Play on this computer' was selected at log on?"

The service runs on WinXP and I use the horrible Mixer* API from C++.

Thanks,
Rickard

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as an OS service, you can't control the volume for a TS user unless you have code running in the TS user's session.  In order to remote audio from the server to the client, the TS service virtualizes all the audio APIs.  Those virtualized controls aren't accessible from Windows services.

In order to solve your program, you'll need come code running in the user's session.  I might suggest a scheduled task which is triggered on user logon.  The [task scheduler APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) allow you to create a task which causes a COM object to be created upon user logon.  From that COM object, you can communicate with your service and then perform the mute operation on behalf of the user.